# How to cast type on imported react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-form

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
import Form as React.Component<IFormProps> from './Form';
```

So that I can then use the component  and it will require the props defined in the **IFormProps** interface.

I am trying to do this, because my Form component uses `redux-form` and `redux`, and the two decorators, simply do not work for me. I've spend too much time googling for examples on how to do this, but nothing works. Here is what my Form export looks like, because nothing else works.

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)((reduxForm as any)(formConfig)(Form)) as any;
```

It really shouldn't be this hard, I have a IFormProps interface inside my Form component, and all I want is for typescript to recognize the required props inside it.

**EDIT:**
As requested I'm adding more info about what my component looks like, but BE WARNED the component is rather complex as far as typings goes. I've had so much trouble getting these connect and redux-form decorators to work, I've had to do a lot of workarounds. And it's wasted a lot of time. At the end of the day, I just need the component to validate against IFormProps, I don't even care if the decorators can't work together. There doesn't seem to be much help in this regard on here or google for that matter. Anyway, more code below:

**Form.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  clearForm,
  doFormSubmit,
  getFormRelatedValues,
  IClearForm,
  IDoFormSubmit,
  IGetFormRelatedValues,
  ISearchFormRelatedValues,
  IUploadFile,
  searchFormRelatedValues,
  uploadFile,
} from '../actions/formActions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';

const { Component } = React;

function onSubmitFail(errors: IDCRA.IGenericObj,
  dispatch: IDCRA.IDispatch,
  submitError: IDCRA.IGenericObj,
  props: IFromProps) {
  // Something....
}

function scrollToFirstError() {
  // Something else....
}

const formConfig = {
  onSubmitFail: (
    errors: IDCRA.IGenericObj,
    dispatch: IDCRA.IDispatch,
    submitError: IDCRA.IGenericObj,
    props: IFromProps,
  ) => scrollToFirstError(errors, props),
  returnRejectedSubmitPromise: true,
  validate: someValidate,
};

declare interface IFromProps {
  // setFormWarningMessage?: (msg: string) => void;
  appContext?: string;
  asyncBlurFields?: string[];
  asyncValidate?: IAsyncValidate;
  change?: IDCRA.IChangeFieldValue;
  clearFormConnect?: IClearForm;
  doFormSubmitConnect?: IDoFormSubmit;
  error?: string;
  fields: { [key: string]: IDCRA.IField };
  firstPage: boolean;
  form: string;
  formObj: IDCRA.IForm;
  formPageIdentifier: string;
  getFormRelatedValuesConnect?: IGetFormRelatedValues;
  goToPrevPage?: () => any;
  handleSubmit?: (fn: (values: IDCRA.IGenericObj, dispatch: IDCRA.IDispatch) => any) => any;
  i18n?: IDCRA.IGenericObj;
  initialValues?: IDCRA.IGenericObj;
  invalid?: boolean;
  isCreateMode: boolean;
  lang: string;
  lastPage: boolean;
  onSubmitSuccess: (response: IDCRA.ISaveCardResponseObj) => any;
  ownerIdentifier: string;
  partialSave?: boolean;
  pristine?: boolean;
  rows: string[][];
  searchFormRelatedValuesConnect?: ISearchFormRelatedValues;
  submitButtonLabel?: string;
  submitFailed?: boolean;
  submitting?: boolean;
  untouch?: IDCRA.IUntouchField;
  uploadFileConnect?: IUploadFile;
  waitForEvent?: boolean;
}

class Form extends Component<IFromProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: IFromProps) {
    super(props);

    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleFormSubmit(values: IDCRA.IGenericObj, dispatch: IDCRA.IDispatch) {
    // Handles form submit....
  }

  render() {
    // Props are consumed here and used to build the form
    const {handleSubmit, identifier} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="form" id={`form-container-${identifier}`}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
          <div className="card bg-default">

            {/* my form parts are here, not important */}

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: IDCRA.IAppState) {
  return {
    appContext: state.appCoreData.appCoreData.appContext,
    i18n: state.appCoreData.appCoreData.i18n,
  };
}

// I have to use my own dispatch type because by default I get errors...
// It's really hard to debug these deply nested TS errors, the messages are cryptic and could be coming from multple source
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: IDCRA.IDispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      // setFormWarningMessage,
      clearFormConnect: clearForm,
      doFormSubmitConnect: doFormSubmit,
      getFormRelatedValuesConnect: getFormRelatedValues,
      searchFormRelatedValuesConnect: searchFormRelatedValues,
      uploadFileConnect: uploadFile,
    },
    dispatch,
  );
}

//  Decorate the form component
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)((reduxForm as any)(formConfig)(Form)) as any;
```

If I remove my **any** casts in the statements from the connect, this is the error I get:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Form' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<IFromProps & InjectedFormProps<{ [x: string]: any; }, IFromProps>>'.
  Type 'typeof Form' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<IFromProps & InjectedFormProps<{ [x: string]: any; }, IFromProps>>'.
    Type 'typeof Form' provides no match for the signature '(props: IFromProps & InjectedFormProps<{ [x: string]: any; }, IFromProps> & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'.
```

If I only leave the any on the reduxForm decorator, I get this error.

```
TS2339: Property 'fields' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.
```

For what its worth, I don't expect anyone to be able to resolve these errors, there's simply too much going on. And I myself have spent several hours trying to get rid of the errors, and it's just been a game of whack-a-mole.

So, at the end of the day, if I could simply overwrite what TS thinks the component exported is, I'll be happy.

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful. Could you share the full source of the `Form.tsx` file? As well as any error message(s) you're getting

Comment: @kingdaro I've added more info, but I'm not sure how helpful it will be. I feel like there's a lot of stuff going on here, but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Oh jeez, I've gotten _pretty_ good at weaving through cryptic errors like that, but those are kind of scary. I could't immediately see how to do this _properly_, but until you can figure that, doing `as any as React.ComponentClass<IFormProps>` at the end of the file will do the trick for now. Definitely not a proper solution, so make sure you leave a comment or something to fix it later :P

Comment: @kingdaro yea unfortunately I've tried that too, which gives another huge error: https://pastebin.com/0j3kwEEZ

Comment: Did you miss the **as any** in there? It's a double cast meant to bypass the type system entirely

Comment: @kingdaro Actually more than an answer, how do I even go about, about analyzing the error that I posted in the bin? Sort of teach a man to fish lol I'm totally lost as to where to even start with that error. What is it trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, I'd know better if I were more familiar with the types for redux and redux-form. The best thing I can suggest is to look up specialized guides on how to use those libraries with typescript specifically, which may give some insight on what puzzle pieces you might be missing here

Comment: @kingdaro Hey just wanted to let you know I got it working :) thanks for the help! If you see anything in my answer that could be improved let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it working by doing this:

```
class Form extends Component<InjectedFormProps & IFromProps, {}> .....
```

And then export like this:

```
export default connect<{}, {}, IFromProps, {}>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(reduxForm(formConfig)(Form));
```

Now my component validates for the correct props!